# Add ticker to Flot bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bar-chart, flot

I have created a chart using Flot library. I need to add a tick mark for showing comparison between last two bars. I am not able to get the height of the bars using any method how can I plot that.

**Here is the example what I am looking for.**

[image]

**I am done with just simple flot chart code which is here. I am not getting how to approach because unable to find any event or anything that give me bar height.**

```js
var data = [
            {data: [[0,1]], color: "red"},
            {data: [[1,2]], color: "yellow"},
            {data: [[2,3]], color: "green"}
           ];

$.plot("#placeholder",data, {
  series: {
    bars: {
      show: true,
      barWidth: 0.3,
      align: "center",
      lineWidth: 0,
      fill:.75
    }
  },
  xaxis: {
    ticks: [[0,"Red"],[1,"Yellow"],[2,"Green"]]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<div id="placeholder" style="width: 400px; height: 300px; padding: 0px; position: relative;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution. There is a marking option in the Flot library itself which I can use. It is not providing me the arrow but atleast I can add a line with it.

```js
var data = [
            {data: [[0,1]], color: "red"},
            {data: [[1,2]], color: "yellow"},
            {data: [[2,3]], color: "green"}
           ];

$.plot("#placeholder",data, {
  series: {
    bars: {
      show: true,
      barWidth: 0.3,
      align: "center",
      lineWidth: 0,
      fill:.75
    },
  },
  grid: {
    markings: [{
      xaxis: { from: 1, to: 2 },
      yaxis: { from: 2, to: 2 },
      color: "#bb0000"
    }]
  },
  xaxis: {
    ticks: [[0,"Red"],[1,"Yellow"],[2,"Green"]]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<div id="placeholder" style="width: 400px; height: 300px; padding: 0px; position: relative;"></div>
```